# Are there any caveats about optimizing a DLL that wouldn't appear in a EXE?

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-optimization, visual-studio-2010

I am generally familiar with the sorts of optimizations performed by the -O2 or -O3 switches.

I have been bitten a couple of times now by issues that are specific to building a DLL that don't appear in writing a flat executable, so before I start turning on optimizations are there any "gotcha"s that I should be aware of?

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722302/can-compiler-optimization-introduce-bugs)

Comment: @sternr Thanks for the link, clearly optimizations can introduce bugs.  I was looking for an idea about common issues that could occur with DLLs that might not be intuitive or produce hard to diagnose problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dead code elimination in an EXE basically starts with `main` as the single root of reachability, but every exported function of a DLL is a separate root.