# Is it safe to link object code compiled with different optimization settings?

Tags: c++, incremental-build

I have a project where I use `make` to recompile only changed files and their dependedants. Sometimes I add `-O0` to debug whereas most code is compiled with `-O2 -march=native`.

It's always the same compiler version. Is it possible to end up with two versions of code (e.g. one previously inlined elsewhere) or constants after linking?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722302/can-compiler-optimization-introduce-bugs

Comment: The elf abi of itanium c++ abi is independent of the optimization level. On the other some macros as `NDEBUG` could change the interface at object file level (even if it could be thought as a bug in the interface).