# Program works fine in Debug build, but fails in Release build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am facing a problem in release build of Visual Studio

pseudo code is given below

```
#include "lib/A/inc/A.h"

main()
{
  A a;
  a.f1();//this fails in release build and works fine in debug build
  a.f2();//this fails in release build and works fine in debug build
}
```

A is derived from B present in lib/B/inc/B.h

```
class A :public B
{
  virtual f2();
};
```

B has a pure virtual function f2() and normal f1()

```
class B {
private:
  string name;
public:
  void f1();
  virtual void f2() = 0;
};
```

I stepped in to the f1() function. At this moment this pointer of  B  has value 0x0000000 and __vfptr is invalid.

But in main() , object a is valid and __vfptr is also valid. Any idea why this happend in release build ?

Comment: could you give real code instead of pseaudo-code?

Comment: Debugging a release build on VC++ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx

Comment: What does it mean when you say "this fails"? (Other than this, Kirill and I have put a lot of effort into formatting your question. Please look at what we've done and learn from it.)

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312312/what-are-some-reasons-a-release-build-would-run-differently-than-a-debug-build

Answer (score 1):

Have a look through some of the differences between a debug and release build and my tips for finding the bug:

[Common reasons for bugs in release version not present in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762088/common-reasons-for-bugs-in-release-version-not-present-in-debug-mode/2810992#2810992)