# Debug exec works fine but normal one segfaults

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, gdb, segmentation-fault

I have the following code :-

```
void someFunc (someStruct* obj) {
    cout << obj->some_member;
}
```

someFunc is a call-back that I get from a library that I have no control over. If I compile this with gdbon=true then the resulting exec works exactly as it is supposed to do. 
On the other hand, if I compile it without the above flag, the exec segfaults. Opening up the core-dump in gdb shows that

```
obj=Variable "obj" is not available.
```

Any ideas on how I can narrow down the problem further (or what might possibly be wrong)?

EDIT:- 
Hey turns out this was a non-issue. There was an unsafe memory access much later in the code which in the release build (what with optimisations and all) appeared to gdb to be a problem in the above line of code. 
What's really surprising is that I tried to do this :-

```
void someFunc (someStruct* obj) {
    if (obj==NULL) return;
    cout<<"here1\n";
    cout<<obj->some_member;
    cout<<"here2\n"
}
```

And this would randomly result in

```
here1
```

sometimes and

```
here1
here2
```

some other times. Which kinda confused me a bit again... 
But the problem was elsewhere...

Comment: I found this excellent question a couple of moments after posting my own. Doesn't seem to help however. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762088/common-reasons-for-bugs-in-release-version-not-present-in-debug-mode

Comment: Try printing out the value of obj. i.e. cout << obj.

Answer (score 1):

try running under valgrind, that should give you some clues